# How to easily retrieve nested firebase realtime database data for a chat app in java?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I am writing a chat app in which I need to check if a two users `u1` and `u2` had a previous conversation or not. If they had, then retrieve the `conversationId` and send messages to that endpoint. Otherwise, create a new conversation.

My datastructure looks something like this.

```
userconversations:
    userId1:
        conversationID1:
            participants:
                user1: true
                user2: true
         conversationID2:
             participants:
                user1: true
                user7: true
```

In my app, I want to read all data from `userconversations/userId1` and iterate over the list to figure out if `user2` is part of a conversation or not.

**My question is how do i design my class so that i quickly deserialize this data and avoid iterating over it using `getChildren()` calls?**

If i normalize the data and keep the a different `conversationId -> participants` mapping, then for each conversationid, i will have to query that stream to get data. Given a user can have 100 conversations, this will be insanely slow and resource intensive.

Please feel free to suggest alternate schema designs which solve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keys `user1`, `user2` and `user7` are dynamic, they can't be automatically serialized into the properties of a POJO. The best you can do is get a `Map<String, boolean>` from `participants` with a GenericTypeIndicator or a cast: `(Map<String, boolean>)snapshot.child("participants").getValue()`.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for the answer. I will try this out.